# Disable browser's context menu of spell checker in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

At the following fiddle http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab of tinymce on doing spell check both the menus are coming:

1. Browser's context menu
2. Spell checker context menu

[image]

I want to disable the browser's right click menu here.

Comment: looks like the event should be canceled and not bubble through

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, running in chrome, executing from the console:

```
$('#previewframe').contents().find('#content_ifr').contents().find(
   '.mceItemHiddenSpellWord').on("contextmenu", function (evt) { evt.preventDefault(); });
```

Works to prevent the right click menu.